# How to find local time in New York, using C++ and Boost?

Tags: c++, boost, timezone

I'm wondering how I can accurately work out the local time in New York using Boost and C++, even if I run the code on a servers located in a range of different countries?

**What I have tried**

I have tried looking at the [Boost C++ examples](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/doc/html/date_time/examples.html) but I couldn't seem to find anything.

Comment: You'll need to do more than look at examples. Did you read the documentation, thoroughly?

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit Fair point, I'm reading through the documentation now.

Comment: you might find this interesting http://home.roadrunner.com/~hinnant/date_algorithms.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For the OP, as well as Matt Johnson, who wanted to see the tz database in use.

```
#include "boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp"
using namespace boost::posix_time;
using namespace boost::gregorian;
#include "boost/date_time/local_time/local_time.hpp"

// form an empty database
boost::local_time::tz_database tz_database;
// load the time zone database which comes with boost
tz_database.load_from_file( "../../boost/libs/date_time/data/date_time_zonespec.csv" ); 

// obtain a specific time zone from the database
boost::local_time::time_zone_ptr tzNewYork;
tzNewYork = tz_database.time_zone_from_region("America/New_York");

// example universal/local conversion (from boost example code)
// ptime now = boost::posix_time::microsec_clock::universal_time();
ptime now(date(2004,Nov,5), hours(10));
boost::local_time::local_date_time ny(now, tzNewYork );
ny.utc_time();  // 10am 2004-Nov-5
ny.local_time();  // 5am 2004-Nov-5
```

Answer (score 5):

First, you need to get the UTC time: you can do that with [`boost::posix_time::second_clock::universal_time()`.](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/date_time/posix_time.html)

From the link you just gave:

```
    //eastern timezone is utc-5
    typedef boost::date_time::local_adjustor<ptime, -5, us_dst> us_eastern;
    // ...
    ptime t3 = us_eastern::utc_to_local(t2);//back should be the same
    std::cout << to_simple_string(t2) << " UTC is " 
          << to_simple_string(t3) << " New York time "
          << "\n\n";
```

To convert it to NY time, just define a local_adjustor for your timezone, and call `utc_to_local` from it.

Comment: How is `us_dst` defined?  I can't seem to locate the docs on that.   Doesn't Boost support IANA zones like `America/New_York`?

Comment: It's a typedef in the `boost::posix_time` namespace. It's defined in `posix_time_types.hpp`.

Specifically, `typedef date_time::us_dst_rules<ptime::date_type, time_duration> us_dst`

Comment: Ah, so then it only knows about the *current* rules for US DST.  All the better to use the IANA TZDB.  [It looks like it can do that](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/date_time/local_time.html#date_time.local_time.tz_database).  An example [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/date_time/examples.html#date_time.examples.seconds_since_epoch)., although that is local to UTC and the OP wanted the reverse.

Comment: You get my +1 still, since the OP didn't ask for anything but the current local time. :)  Still, I'd love to see an augmented answer showing the TZDB usage.

Comment: hmm now for me to figure out the c++11 version of this =)